# Insertar formulario en template AdminLTE-2.3.11 y codeigniter 3

Tags: codeigniter

me encuentro nuevo aprendiendo CI, estoy intentando integrar un formulario al template de AdminLTE justo en la parte de contenido:

```
<section class="content">
 <?= $this->load->view('registrarCatalogacion');?>
</section>
<!-- /.content -->
```

Actualmente me sale este error: Message: Object of class CI_Loader could not be converted to string, me podrían por favor decir la forma correcta de hacerlo o en que estoy mal?. Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema es que estas imprimiendo la view.

cuando escribes

```
<?= $variable; ?>
```

es equivalente a:

```
<?php echo $variable; ?>
```

para que te funcione, debes ponerlo asi:

```
 <?php $this->load->view('registrarCatalogacion'); ?>
```

Comment: Si gracias, ya la había visto por allá en un blog, pero gracias por tu respuesta.